# WooCommerce | woocommerce_email_before_order_table function call not working on initial email send but works on status change

Tags: php, email, woocommerce

I've added some additional settings fields to customer emails and I'm outputting the saved values to the all customer email templates with callback to the `woocommerce_email_before_order_table` hook.

I'm testing the order processing order email specifically. When this email is sent after the order is made the data is not present in the email. But. Upon status change to processing, the email **does** contain the data.

**Simplified example below**

Add fields to emails

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_classes', 'add_settings', 9999 );
function add_settings( $email_class_list ) {
    foreach( $email_class_list as $email_class ) {
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_settings_api_form_fields_' . $email_class->id, 'the_fields', 10, 1 );
    }

    return $email_class_list;
}
```

The fields

```
function the_fields( $form_fields ) {

    $form_fields['field_id_one'] = array( 
        'title'         => 'Title',
        'description'   => 'This text will appear above the email templats default content',
        'type'          => 'textarea',
        'default'       => '',
    );

    $form_fields['field_id_two'] = array( 
        'title'         => 'Title',
        'description'   => 'This text will appear above the email templats default content',
        'type'          => 'textarea',
        'default'       => '',
    );

    return $form_fields;
}
```

Display data in the email

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'display_in_email', 20, 4 );
function display_in_email( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    echo wpautop( $email->get_option( 'field_id_one' ) );
}
```

I have tried just echoing out some arbitrary text and with the data working on status change it's not an issue with the code inside the callback.

I'm making this call from a file in a plugin.

Comment: Could you update your question by adding all the affected code? You most likely save the data after the email is sent.

Comment: The data is in the database. It's saved during saving the specific email options. I added the fields via the `woocommerce_settings_api_form_fields_` filter and therefore they are saved via the WC_Settings_API class. I've added full code.

Comment: Is the data saved as a custom meta of the order? Are the custom fields found in the checkout? Is it important to save this data as email options? Or is your goal simply to show this data in the body of the email?

Comment: Body of the email. It's a very basic task. And it works but not on first email send. Add a field to the existing settings array, which is saved to options table and then display that option in the email. It works in other emails too. Just not the first order received email initiated by the checkout. But that same email works when initiated by a manual status change. It's not order related and, I could override the template in a theme, but why also is a hook not working?

Comment: I tried your code and it works for me. To do a test, I just added the `default` key of each field with placeholder text. In every first email received, I correctly display the content of the `field_id_one` field. The templates are these: `WC_Email_New_Order`, `WC_Email_Customer_On_Hold_Order` and `WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order`. **Try increasing the filter priority like this**: `add_filter( 'woocommerce_settings_api_form_fields_' . $email_class->id, 'the_fields', 9999, 1 );`